# moving things after a transition change in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I asked a question previously about some layout issues I have when transitioning from landscape to portrait. I asked here but got no response. After analyzing the issue I think my problem is that I am calling out the repositioning method on viewWillTransition:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    resetPositions()
}

func resetPositions() {
    if isMainContainer {
        if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
            containerViewBot.center.y = containedView.center.y
            containerViewBotBack.center.y = containedView.center.y - offset
        } else {
            containerViewBot.center.x = self.view.center.x
            containerViewBotBack.center.x = self.view.center.x - offset
        }
    } else {
        if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
            containerViewBotBack.center.y = containedView.center.y
            containerViewBot.center.y = containedView.center.y + offset
        } else {
            containerViewBotBack.center.x = self.view.center.x
            containerViewBot.center.x = self.view.center.x + offset
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to know how to call this method AFTER the transition, something like
`viewDidFinishTransition` or how can I call the resetPosition method AFTER the windows were re-arranged into their new mode (landscape / portrait).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put your resetPositions() in completion block of coordinator's animate method.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { (context) in
            resetPositions()
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI - this moves things *during* the transition, not after.

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick somehow!. Just for learning purposes, what does (context) do here? what does it mean? or is it just an arbitrary name?

Comment: animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)

method used if you want to perform some kind of animation along with controller transition animations.


And context Provide info about ViewController transition.ex: context.transitionDuration.
yes you can replace it with your own name because it’s parameter of completion clouser(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator/1619300-animate)

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `coordinator` parameter. It is of type `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` which provides a call you can make that will be done after the transition is done (or along with the transition as needed.

Also read this from the documentation for `viewWillTransition`:

> If you override this method in your custom view controllers, always call super at some point in your implementation so that UIKit can forward the size change message appropriately.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.notifyWhenInteractionChanges { (context) in
        // Called after the transition
        resetPositions()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just for learning purposes, what does (context) do here? what is (context), is it just a generic name can I replace it with whatever or is it an actual command?

Comment: It's the variable name for the completion handler's parameter.